# Problema ao alimentar banco de dados através de formulário em php

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Bom galera, to fazendo uns testes com um banco de dados, porém to tendo um problema em que por algum motivo, as informações não estão sendo enviadas.

Os códigos estão  em arquivos diferentes;

Tenho um arquivo chamado cadastro.html:

```html
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Cadastro de Ativos</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Cadastro de Ativos</h1>
<br>

<form action="verifica.php" method="post">

<pre>
Insira as informações do ativo para cadastrar.

Empresa: <input type="text" size="35" maxlength="256" name="empresa">
Filial:  <input type="text" size="35" maxlenght="256" name="filial">
Segmento:<input type="text" size="35" maxlenght="256" name="segmento">

<input type="submit" value="Efetuar Cadastro" name="enviar">
</pre>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Outro chamado verifica.php:

```html
<html>
<body>
<?php

$empresa            =   $_POST["empresa"];      
$filial             =   $_POST["filial"]; 
$segmento           =   $_POST["segmento"]; 
$erro               =   0;  

//Verifica se o campo empresa não está em branco
if (empty($empresa))
{echo "Favor digitar a empresa corretamente.<br>"; $erro=1;}
//Verifica se o campo filial está preenchido corretamente
if (empty($filial))
{echo "Favor digitar o filial corretamente.<br>"; $erro=1;}
//Verifica se o campo segmento está preenchido corretamente
if (empty($segmento))
{echo "Favor digitar o segmento corretamente.<br>"; $erro=1;}
//Verifica se não houve erro - neste caso chama a include para inserir os dados
if ($erro=0)
{echo "Ativo cadastrado com súcesso!";
include 'insere.inc';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Outro chamado insere.inc

```html
<?php

include 'conecta_mysql.inc';

$empresa            = $_POST['empresa'];
$filial             = $_POST['filial'];
$segmento           = $_POST['segmento'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO ativos VALUES";
$sql .= "('$empresa', '$filial', '$segmento')";

if ($conexao->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Ativo cadastrado com súcesso!";
} else {
    echo "Erro: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conexao->error;
}

$conexao->close();
```

e outro chamado: conecta_mysql.inc:

```html
<? php
         //cria a conexao mysqli_connect('localizacao BD', 'usuario de acesso', 'senha', 'banco de dados')
         $conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'tedinfo1_admin1', 'admin1', 'tedinfo1_app');

         //ajusta o charset de comunicação entre a aplicação e o banco de dados
         mysqli_set_charset($conexao, 'utf8');

         //verifica a conexão
         if ($conexao->connect_error) {
            die("Falha ao realizar a conexão: " . $conexao->connect_error);
}
```

Ao enviar as informações, a tela fica toda branca, além das informações não chegarem na minha db.

Grato desde já pela atenção de vocês.

---

Segue o print de como está configurado no banco de dados

[image: configuração db]

realizei a alteração mas ainda não funciona.

Comment: Como está a tabela `ativos` (só existe essas tres colunas)?

Comment: porque fez assim `$sql = "INSERT INTO ativos VALUES"; $sql .= "('$empresa', '$filial', '$segmento')";`, faz assim `$sql = "INSERT INTO ativos VALUES ('$empresa', '$filial', '$segmento')";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua tabela parece ter quatro colunas, não somente três (existe o `id`, que não é preenchido por você). Sendo assim, me parece que você tem que especificar quais deles quer preencher.

```
$empresa            = $conexao->real_escape_string($_POST['empresa']);
$filial             = $conexao->real_escape_string($_POST['filial']);
$segmento           = $conexao->real_escape_string($_POST['segmento']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO ativos (`empresa`, `filial`, `segmento`) VALUES ('$empresa', '$filial', '$segmento')";

if ($conexao->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Ativo cadastrado com súcesso!";
} else {
    echo "Erro: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conexao->error;
}
```